# using ints to increment through a string array for each method invocation

Tags: java, arrays, methods

In a class I have a method here that should add to the int `mWeight` for each invocation, then for every three times it is invoked, move through the `mSize` array. In the main method where I'm invoking the getter, I'm not getting any higher string values in the array.

Here are the relevant class variables and the getter.

```
// Amount of weight to gain after eating
    final float WEIGHT_GAIN = 0.25f;

 // Its weight in pounds
    float mWeight;

// Size, either "tiny", "small", "average", or "large"
    String mSize[] = {"tiny", "small", "average", "large"};

 int dogSize;

String getSize(){
    return mSize[dogSize];
```

The method and what it needs to do.

```
/*
 * feed
 *
 * Feeds the Dog.
 *
 * Side-effect: 1. The Dog gains weight, specifically WEIGHT_GAIN
 *              2. Every 3 meals, the Dog grows to a larger size, if
 *                 possible
 *                 i.e. "tiny" (3 meals later ->) "small" (3 meals later ->)
 *                 "average" (3 meals later ->) "large"
 *                 the Dog cannot exceed the "large" size or shrink smaller than
 *                 "tiny"
 * @return nothing
 */ 

void feed(){
    while(mWeight < mSize.length)
    mWeight ++;
    mWeight = mWeight * WEIGHT_GAIN; 
    dogSize += (int)mWeight/3;
    if (dogSize > mSize.length)
    dogSize = mSize.length;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you forget curly braces after the `while` ? Where is `dogSize` declared ?

Comment: When I see "for every three times it is invoked" I'm thinking instance scope counter and the modulo operator.

Comment: Edit made. `dogGender` should have been `dogSize`, declaired in the member variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a variable for number of meals the dog has taken.

```
final float WEIGHT_GAIN = 0.25f;
String mSize[] = {"tiny", "small", "average", "large"};
class Dog{
        int num_meals, mWeight, dogSize;
        public Dog(int weight){
            num_meals = 0;
            dogSize = 0;
            mWeight = weight;
        }
        public String getSize(){
            return mSize[dogSize];
        }
        void feed(){
            mWeight += mWeight * WEIGHT_GAIN;
            num_meals++;
            dogSize = num_meals/3 < mSize.length-1 ? num_meals/3 : mSize.length - 1; 
        }
}
```